# How to show the value in child path firebase-realtime?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

`Why imageURL can't save the value when i call in other function??

After I investigated the problem further, the problem was that inside the saveQrCodeToStorage function in the addOnSuccessListener command I was taking the image URL then storing it inside the imageURL in the parent class. When I try the println("Image download URL: $imageURL") command in the saveQrCodeToStorage function below the Log.i line, imageURL still manages to save the URL value. However, when I call the command println("Image download URL: $imageURL") outside the saveQrCodeToStorage function, to be precise, in the uploadData function below the Toast "Created" line, the imageURL value is null, which means the value has gone somewhere. that's the problem i can't find the stored value it just disappeared where did it cause.

Can anyone help me, please?

this is my Main Code`

```
package com.example.loginandsignupfirebase

class NewTraceabilityActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityNewTraceabilityBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var firebaseref : DatabaseReference
    private var imageURL : String? = null
    var uri : Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityNewTraceabilityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        firebaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Product")

        binding.closeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        binding.createTraceabilityBtn.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }
    }

class NewTraceabilityActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        binding.createTraceabilityBtn.setOnClickListener {
            saveData()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")
    private fun saveData(){
        uploadData()
        dialog.dismiss()

    }

    private fun uploadData(){

        val newProductID = firebaseref.push()
        val pid = newProductID.key!!

        val farmer = binding.farmerEt.text.toString()
        val variety = binding.varietytEt.text.toString()
        val weight = binding.weightEt.text.toString()

        val currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().time)

        val qrCodeBitMap = generateQrCode(pid)
        saveQrCodeToStorage(pid, qrCodeBitMap)

        val dataClass = DataClass(pid, farmer, variety, weight, currentDate, imageURL)

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(firebaseAuth.uid.toString()).child("pid").child(pid)
            .setValue(dataClass).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Toast.makeText(this@NewTraceabilityActivity, "get $pid successfully from firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startActivity(Intent(this, TraceabilityListActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Toast.makeText(this, e.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    private fun saveQrCodeToStorage(pid: String, qrCodeBitmap: Bitmap) {
        val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storageRef = storage.reference

        val qrCodeRef: StorageReference = storageRef.child("qr_codes/$pid.jpg")

        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        qrCodeBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val data: ByteArray = baos.toByteArray()

        qrCodeRef.putBytes(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                taskSnapshot.metadata?.reference?.downloadUrl
                val uriTask = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl
                while (!uriTask.isComplete);
                val urlImage = uriTask.result
                imageURL = urlImage.toString()

                Log.i(
                    "QrCode",
                    "Success upload photo to storage firebase")

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                // Upload gagal
                // Lakukan tindakan yang diperlukan jika terjadi kesalahan
                Log.e(
                    "QrCode",
                    "something wrong with save qrCode to firebase: ${exception.message}"
                )
            }
    }

}
```

this my class DataClass

```
class DataClass {
    var pid: String? = null
    var dataFarmer: String? = null
    var dataVariety: String? = null
    var dataWeight: String? = null
    var dataDate: String? = null
    var dataQrCode: String? = null

    constructor(pid: String?, dataFarmer: String?, dataVariety: String?, dataWeight: String?, dataDate: String?, dataQrCode:String?){
        this.pid = pid
        this.dataFarmer = dataFarmer
        this.dataVariety = dataVariety
        this.dataWeight = dataWeight
        this.dataDate = dataDate
        this.dataQrCode = dataQrCode
    }

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is that you're trying to fix.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what specifically isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: ok thank for ur suggestion, i was edited my problem to be more specific. i hope anyone can help this problem.

Comment: Firebase API are asynchronous and return immediately.  The callback is invoked some time later when the operation completes.  You will need to learn how to do asynchronous programming on Android to use Firebase correctly.

Comment: That's indeed what the problem is. Firebase API is asynchronous. Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).